# How to check if a reference to a view is inside another view in android?

Tags: android

There is no requirement that a view have an unique id.  You can inflate a view an then add that view into another view. eg.

```
  myFooterReference = inflate (my_footer)
  myListView.addFooterView(myFooterReference)
```

Is it then always valid to call ?

```
 myListView.removeFooterView(myFooterReference)
```

We do not now have an option to first check

```
 myListView.findViewById(R.id.my_footer_id) // because no such footer exists
```

So whats up with this guys?  Is it always valid to try to remove a view by reference even it its not there.  Has anyone else ever gotten errors doing this?

Any theory on why android sdk does not have a method:

```
  myListView.hasView(listViewReference);
```

or at least

```
  myListView.hasFooterView(listViewReference) ?
```

It has a count of items but why not a method to tell if a given footer is there?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent of your view:

```
view.getParent();
```

And check if it has parent and is it's parent your listview or no?

But if you don't like these checks,generally the best solution would be to just implement your own layout manager that does your desired layout, as needed, and can also keep track of interesting views it has in it.
See this page:[Check if a View contains another View](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/B_2UHIUPcMo).

Comment: I see so you are suggesting if (view.getParent == containingView) then the list is contained.

Comment: Do think this would reliably work for a footer view inside a list view?